# PostgreSQL group timestamp by date and truncate time

Tags: postgresql

The table schema is like this:

```
Column |           Type           |                    Modifiers                     
--------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------
time   | timestamp with time zone | default now()
```

The time format is like this:

```
          time          
------------------------
 2016-07-11 18:58:28+00
 2016-07-11 18:58:37+00
 2016-07-12 00:59:31+00
```

How to group by date with time truncated?

I would like to see the result as:

```
          date          
------------------------
       2016-07-11 
       2016-07-11
       2016-07-12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want compare or group by dates instead of timestamps you can cast to `DATE`:

```
SELECT time::DATE, ... FROM ... GROUP BY time::DATE;
```

or simpler

```
SELECT time::DATE, ... FROM ... GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the current Postgresql documentation for datetime functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

You can use `date_trunc`, `extract`, `to_char` or the simplest way is to cast to `date` (as I would do):

```
SELECT time::date; // 2016-07-11 18:58:28+00 -> 2016-07-11
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use date_trunc:

```
 select date_trunc('day', time)
```